# double quoted parameter in C function call

Tags: c

Apologies if I was unable to find this answered elsewhere.  I think I have figured out what is going on, but I wanted to check in with more knowledgeable people.

I am looking at some C code for GPIB communication.  One of the functions from the API I am using has a void* parameter.  This parameter is meant to be the command you wish to send to the instrument on the bus, so I gather it's declared to be void* because it will be raw bytes.

In the example code for using this API, the call to this function has that parameter within double quotes.  If I remove the double quotes, the compiler complains about an undeclared identifier.

I was at first confused, thinking double quotes is a string literal, but here's what I'm thinking is going on - to pass a literal to a function, it has to be enclosed in double quotes (otherwise, the undeclared identifier error).  The string literal is then implicitly converted to a void* - is that correct?

Thank you.

Comment: Just give us some code. Code worth a thousand words.

Comment: You're passing a string literal to that function. There's nothing else going on. (And yes that gets converted from char* to void* - which does absolutely nothing to the data you're passing).

Answer (score 1):

A void pointer is a pointer with no *specific* underlying type. It can be freely converted to or from any other pointer, and it's commonly used in situations where *any* pointer may be used.

In the context of your question, you seem to be stating that you have a function like:

```
void someFn (void *param);
```

and that you call it with:

```
someFun ("pax_is_really_great");
```

and that works. Nothing wrong there, it *should* work, the `char *` is implicitly converted into a `void *` as part of the function call. You could just as easily do:

```
int xyzzy = 42;
someFun (&xyzzy);
```

and the `int *` pointer to the `xyzzy` variable will be converted to `void *` as well. Whether that will work at runtime depends upon what `someFn` *does* with the pointer, but it's perfectly acceptabe at compile time.

When you remove the quotes from your C string, you end up with:

```
someFun (pax_is_really_great);
```

and the compiler then thinks you're trying to find an identifier (such as a variable) called `pax_is_really_great` to pass in. And, while that variable usually exists in *my* code, I'd understand why the rest of the planet may not have one in their code :-)

So, you'll be likely to get an error from your compiler stating that you haven't declared that variable anywhere.

Bottom line, you mostly have it right. You may see lines like:

```
sendGpib ("\x00\x05hello");
```

and the pointer would point at the following bytes, with some mythical explanations:

```
0x00    command to write a string (len/data)
0x05    five chars to write
'h'     chars to write
'e'
'l'
'l'
'o'
(unused string NUL terminator)
```

There are other ways you could construct the data, such as:

```
char buff[] = {0, 5, 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
sendGpib (buff);
```

but it all boils down to ensuring you have a buffer somewhere that will go to the function as a void pointer.

Comment: That missing comma itches me, but is not enough characters to edit it myself :p

Comment: @Quentin, and yet you had the time for the comment? :-) Never mind, I fixed it, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Not a matter of time, SO won't actually let me edit less that 6 characters.